# ChangeNotifierProvider does not update the model

Tags: flutter, provider

i am quite new with flutter. I am trying to add a `ChangeNotifierProvider` into my app. I use `flutter_azure_b2c` to log in a user, in order to handle to login outcome I have the following code:

```
AzureB2C.registerCallback(B2COperationSource.POLICY_TRIGGER_INTERACTIVE,
    (result) async {
  if (result.reason == B2COperationState.SUCCESS) {
    List<String>? subjects = await AzureB2C.getSubjects();

    if (subjects != null && subjects.isNotEmpty) {
      B2CAccessToken? token = await AzureB2C.getAccessToken(subjects[0]);
      if (!mounted || token == null) return;
      final encodedPayload = token.token.split('.')[1];
      final payloadData =
          utf8.fuse(base64).decode(base64.normalize(encodedPayload));
      final claims = Claims.fromJson(jsonDecode(payloadData));
      var m = Provider.of<LoginModel>(context);
      m.logIn(claims);
    }
  }
});
```

The problem is that when it arrives to `var m = Provider.of<LoginModel>(context);` the execution stops with out errors without executing `m.logIn(claims);`, so the model is not changed and the consumer is not called.

Any idea?

This is my consumer:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => LoginModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: appTheme,
          home: Consumer<LoginModel>(
            builder: (context, value, child) =>
                value.claims != null ? const Home() : const Login(),
          )),
    );
  }
}



class LoginModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  Claims? _claims;

  logIn(Claims claims) {
    _claims = claims;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  logOut() {
    _claims = null;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Claims? get claims => _claims;
}
```

My LoginWidget:

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  LoginState createState() => LoginState();
}

class LoginState extends State<Login> {
  B2CConfiguration? _configuration;

  checkLogin(BuildContext context) async {
    List<String>? subjects = await AzureB2C.getSubjects();

    if (subjects != null && subjects.isNotEmpty) {
      B2CAccessToken? token = await AzureB2C.getAccessToken(subjects[0]);
      if (!mounted || token == null) return;
      final encodedData = token.token.split('.')[1];
      final data =
          utf8.fuse(base64).decode(base64.normalize(encodedData));
      final claims = Claims.fromJson(jsonDecode(data));
      var m = Provider.of<LoginModel>(context, listen: true);
      m.logIn(claims); //<-- debugger never reaches this line
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // It is possible to register callbacks in order to handle return values
    // from asynchronous calls to the plugin
    AzureB2C.registerCallback(B2COperationSource.INIT, (result) async {
      if (result.reason == B2COperationState.SUCCESS) {
        _configuration = await AzureB2C.getConfiguration();
        if (!mounted) return;
        await checkLogin(context);
      }
    });

    AzureB2C.registerCallback(B2COperationSource.POLICY_TRIGGER_INTERACTIVE,
        (result) async {
      if (result.reason == B2COperationState.SUCCESS) {
        if (!mounted) return;
        await checkLogin(context);
      }
    });

    // Important: Remeber to handle redirect states (if you want to support
    // the web platform with redirect method) and init the AzureB2C plugin
    // before the material app starts.
    AzureB2C.handleRedirectFuture().then((_) => AzureB2C.init("auth_config"));

    const String assetName = 'assets/images/logo.svg';
    final Widget logo = SvgPicture.asset(
      assetName,
    );

    return SafeArea(
      child: //omitted,
    );
  }
}
```

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/804) as well, but it did not help me.

Comment: can you include morea about `logIn`

Comment: I added it, but the point is that it is never called.

Comment: You can try with passing the context on the method on that case

Comment: Sorry, dont understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, moving the callback registrations from the `build` method to the `initState` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
 `var m = Provider.of<LoginModel>(context, listen: false)._claims;`

You are using the Provider syntax but not doing anything really with it. You need to set it like this `Provider.of<LoginModel>(context, listen: false).login(claims)` and call it like this `Provider.of<LoginModel>(context, listen: false)._claims;`

Comment: Editing the code, using directly the variable and not the getter, same problem.

Comment: Try changing `Claims? _claims;` to `Claims? claims;` in your LoginModel class

Comment: Already done, but problem still persists.

Comment: Then there is no issue with the Provider, what you are doing is calling provider before you have received data, so you need to first make sure what ever the data is you are downloading or the task you are doing is completed then use the provider, right now you are updating provider with empty values, this is why there is no errors because nothing is happening as there is no values in it

Comment: `final claims = await Claims.fromJson(jsonDecode(data));` try to print this data, see if it is complete, This seems to be the issue